# Border of qgroupbox

Tags: qt, border, groupbox

I'm having some trouble setting a border of a groupbox.

my aim is to have something like this:

[image]

but so far all I can get is this:

[image]

the stylesheet i'm using:

```
#groupBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
QGroupBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 9px;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exacly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    left: 3px;
    padding: 3 0 3 0;
}
```

for the title, to adjust the title more properly.