# Qt QGroupBox border

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qtstylesheets

Im working on a little program that require a `QGroupBox` that have inside a `QLineEdit`. I want to make "invisible" the border of the `QGroupBox` using:

```
groupBoxName->setStyleSheet("border:0;");
```

The problem is that even the `QLineEdit` inside of it inherit this style.
How can I make invisible the `QGroupBox` border but not the `QLineEdit` border?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`QGroupBox::setFlat`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#flat-prop)?

Comment: Yes and it add a line above the widget. Is now my current "solution" but it is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QGroupBox border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306019/qgroupbox-border)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give an object name for the groupbox using setObjectName() function,

```
group_box->setObjectName("MyBox");
```

Then you could style it as a css object.

```
group_box->setStyleSheet("#MyBox{border:0
```

This will only affect the #MyBox

Comment: It works!
Finally that border is gone!
Thanks a lot for the answer.